# Sort isotope is not working properly after adding new div

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I have used isotope to sort divs by attribute value. But when I add new div or edit one of the existing div. Then sorting is not working properly. THe newly created or edited div is added at end of list of divs, even if the div's sort order is middle. My code is given below.
Thanks.

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="subContainer" data-order="4">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="subContainer" data-order="1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="subContainer" data-order="3">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="subContainer" data-order="2">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, Please add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use isotope `addItems` or `insert` methods that adds new content to an Isotope container :

```
$('.mainContainer').append( $newItems ).isotope( 'addItems', $newItems );
$('.mainContainer').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );
```

Or use `reloadItems` with sort parameter `sortBy` :

```
$('.mainContainer').isotope('reloadItems'); 
$('.mainContainer').isotope({sortBy:'original-order'});
```

**Sort function :**

```
$('.mainContainer').find('.subContainer').sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.getAttribute('data-order') - +b.getAttribute('data-order');     
}).appendTo('.mainContainer');
```

Hope this helps.